# In a commutative rng with comaximal ideals, product equals intersection as well?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, rngs

In a commutative ring $R$ with unity, the product of every two comaximal ideals equals their intersection, that is, if $I + J = R$, then $I\cap J = IJ$.

The proof I know involves the unity of $R$, so that $1 = i + j$, and then $x = x\cdot 1= xi + xj = ix + xj \in IJ$.

> Now, what if $R$ is a commutative rng, that is, without identity? Is it still true that $IJ = I\cap J$?

Comment: How about $R = 2\mathbb{Z}$ and $I = 4\mathbb{Z}, J = 6\mathbb{Z}$? It seems to me that we have $I +J = R$, but $IJ = 24\mathbb{Z}$ whereas $I \cap J = 12\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Of course, this generalizes quite easily. You can come up with similar examples by taking any ring $S$ with ideals $I, J$ such that $I \cap J$ properly contains $IJ$, and then set $R = I+J$.